# why drupal webform form setting shows mysql errors in dblog?

Tags: webforms

I have created one webform in Drupal 7 in which some form components are present. But when I'm going to view that webform the components(fields) are not displayed. Then I checked in form setting that form was closed but when I'm going to change the form setting to open and saving that form I'm getting error *"The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later"*. Then in dblog there was the following mysql error.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062
>   Duplicate entry '39055' for key 1: INSERT INTO {webform} (nid,
>   confirmation, confirmation_format, redirect_url, status, block,
>   teaser, allow_draft, auto_save, submit_notice, submit_text,
>   submit_limit, submit_interval, total_submit_limit,
>   total_submit_interval) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_9, :db_insert_placeholder_10,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_11, :db_insert_placeholder_12,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_13, :db_insert_placeholder_14); Array (
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 39055 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] =>
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => full_html [:db_insert_placeholder_3] =>
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 0
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => 0
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_9] => 0
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_10] => [:db_insert_placeholder_11] => -1
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_12] => -1 [:db_insert_placeholder_13] => -1
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_14] => -1 ) in drupal_write_record() (line
>   7194 of /home/indiawaterportal/public_html/includes/common.inc).

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You have an auto-increment problem on your table. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872215/mysql-duplicate-entry-error-for-key-with-auto-increment .

Comment: I have given ID field type as auto increment and it's also a primary key. Then what is the problem there?

Comment: I've made mistake in previous comment- there is no any auto increment field in webform. No I'm not using custom webform.

Comment: It's not a question of webform fields, it's your webform nid.

Comment: Webform ID is auto increment field.

Comment: Yes, and your sql database seems to be mixed up, that why i pointed you to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872215/mysql-duplicate-entry-error-for-key-with-auto-increment to solve this.

Comment: Sorry but there is no auto increment for webform ID. Again I've tested my database

Answer (score 0):

> INSERT INTO {webform} (nid...

tries to insert the nid of the webform (got from auto-increment in the node table) in the {webform} table. So, every nid inserted in nid column of webform table should be unique. But it seems that the newly-created webform node got a nid that already exists in webform's nid column.

So I guess there's something wrong. Find that nid in webform table, see if it exists in node table, that must be the trick.

Comment: Yes, nid is there in the webform table. Then what's wrong there?

Comment: is 39055 also in webform table's nid column ?

Comment: yes 39055 is webform nid.

Comment: Then delete your form and re-build it... :(

Comment: But that's not the solution I think.

Comment: But what about submissions of that form because due to that form error we are not able to import that.